# vba code to convert string from a cell to date format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to read a date in the form of string from a cell and convert it into a date format and use it in my vba program. Could someone help me out with the steps?

thanks a tonne in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have string on cell F6, you can do something line this to covert this string to date

```
Sub convert()

Dim str1 As String
str1 = Range("f6").Value

startdate = CDate(str1)

End Sub
```

Comment: now I have another problem. I'm currently in a sub and activated a sheet( say x), but the entered date(as string) is in sheet(say y). how do I activate y for this date conversion alone?(i'm calling a sub from this point and using the converted date in the called function). I need to get back to x after this function is done.

Comment: most of the time, you don't need to activate the sheet at all. Call your range as in `sheets("Y").range("F6")` and all will be well, regardless of the active sheet.

Comment: @user3067096 if the solution has helped you mark it as accepted answer. Regarding your second problem use something like `sheets("Y").range("F6").value`